# Can i change the volume of my AUDIO FILE without changing the SYSTEM volume in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio, volume

I am working on a flutter project where I want to play multiple sounds simultaneously and I want to change the volume for specific audio without changing the volume of other audios or the system volume.

I have tried various Flutter Libraries but couldn't work it out. Please help if anyone knows.

The application is similar to [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.metapps.sleepsounds&hl=en).

Comment: With some audio file formats (mp3) you can indeed change the volume in the file. There are many programs that do this. Checkout: https://www.iskysoft.com/video-editing/mp3-volume-editor.html to see how. Also read the mp3 standard: http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try audioplayers flutter plugin. The plugin can control the sound(volume parameter) and can play multiple files.

https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers